# Material UI styling the onFocus Select component

Tags: javascript, material-ui

I am trying to style the select component in Mui, but I'm not able to achieve what I want. I have a global styles in my App.tsx that handles different situations, but I want to add a specific style in this component.

Here's what I have:

```
const useSelectStyles = makeStyles((theme: ITheme) => ({
  root: {
    width: "27rem",
    '& fieldset.Mui-focused': {
      color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0)',
    },
    '& input.Mui-focused': {
      color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0)',
    },
    '& .Mui-focused': {
      color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0)',
    },
    '&.Mui-focused': {
      color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0)',
    },
    '.Mui-focused': {
      color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0)',
    },
  },
  '.Mui-focused': {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
  listbox: {
    padding: '0',
  },
  option: {
    padding: '0.5rem 1rem',
  },
}));
```

What am I doing wrong here? After selection, the background becomes gray, and I can't seem to change it white.

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-glade-0b3v5?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: The culprit seems to be this style `.MuiInputBase-input:focus`. But unfortunately, I am not familiar enough with Material UI to be of more help.

Comment: I've figured it out. Code in the sandbox.